# I'm having trouble importing from mutually .py files

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I work with PyQt5, I am trying to import another .py file containing a QWidget class from a .py file containing a QMainWindow class, but I get the following error.

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\PYTHON\PyQt5 Dersleri\Farmakoloji\grup_init_.py", line 6, in <module>
    from __init__ import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\PYTHON\PyQt5 Dersleri\Farmakoloji\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from grup_init_ import ilac_gruplari
ImportError: cannot import name 'ilac_gruplari' from 'grup_init_' (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\PYTHON\PyQt5 Dersleri\Farmakoloji\grup_init_.py)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your `__init__.py` has this in it `from grup_init_ import ilac_gruplari`, but `grup_init_.py` does not have `ilac_gruplari` to import from it - you need to share `grup_init_.py` or at least the part you would consider relevant for people to give you more specific advice.